# Traceroute works (very slowly) but internet doesn't work

Tags: ping, traceroute

[image: Traceroute very slow]

[image: Ping doesn't work]

Ping doesn't work.

And can't connect through Firefox. When entering IP in URL bar it shows "The connection has timed out, The server at 35.1.1.48 is taking too long to respond." after like a minute. When entering translated names "Server not found, Firefox can't find the server at www.google.com" after like a minute.

It's openSUSE on virtual machine VMware Workstation 12 Player, used as a Teradata server. It has static adress 192.168.1.100. I can connect to my internal network, create tables and insert data and I see in virtual machine that data in the database. But I need the connection with external network.

edit: ping actually works but you have to wait a lot for first packet to arrive. I waited at least 10 minutes and there was not one packet that arrived. When I CTRL+C'ed this showed up: i.imgur.com/NgXggjE.png (sorry, it doesnt let to me to post a link or embed a picture here) 99% packet loss

Comment: That's fun. I too would like to read an answer to this question. That is behavior I have never seen.

Answer (score 0):

First of all need to understand if the problem in virtual machine(VM) or host machine(host).
 To be sure that problem is on VM, you needs simply repeat on host all your attempts that you did on VM. If on host everything is fine, then problem is or on VM or in VMware config.

If you see that on host everything is fine, then you need to answer on those questions:

1. From VM there in no access to all sites or only 35.1.1.48?
2. From VM there is no ping to all external IPs or only 35.1.1.48?
   If you have problem only with 1 site, then problem is not with your VM.
3. Only that VM(openSUSE) make you the problems, or all of them that you has on your host?
4. How do you get IP(192.168.100.1) on your VM? Via DHCP or you setup it manually? If you receive IP from DHCP server that is not your host, but some other network device, that also gives IP to host, then your network config suppose to be fine.
5. If all checks above didn't gave you clear answer where is the problem, then check your iptables in VM, maybe you block access.

If nothing helps, then make topology simpler, that will exclude values from the topology, and it will be easier to find the issue. For example:

1. do not setup manually your network, use DHCP
2. install another simple VM, like ubuntu with everything preconfigured (plug & play). Check if that Ubuntu works fine. If not, then you have issue in your VMware config.

Comment: Yes, on host internet works all right.
1. Other does not work either.

Comment: 2. I checked other IPs too, and it's the same. But i just find out ping actually works but also, as traceroute, very slow. I waited at least 10 minutes and there was not one packet that arrived. When I CTRL+C'ed this showed up: http://i.imgur.com/NgXggjE.png 99% packet loss

Comment: 3. I don't have other VM.

4. The adress is 192.168.1.100 and it's not from DHCP, i was worried there could be issues if the server changes IP, so i set it to be static in openSUSE's YaST2 Netword Card application.

Comment: 5. iptables -L is empty http://i.imgur.com/cJvceTg.png

Comment: 1)Try to setup IP via DHCP server of your local network. To be sure that you didn't mess up with network config.

Comment: 2)You can install mtr (zypper install mtr)? It's combination of ping and traceroute. Thanks to mtr you can see on what point start huge packet loss, if that point is your local pc, than you know where to search for the problem.

Answer (score 0):

What ip addressing you are using in the server, if its static i suppose you are giving the gateway and DNS correct.If its from DHCP, Try connecting the cable to another PC and check weather able to connect to external network and try opening google for that matter.

Comment: It's static and i set the gateway, you can see it in first picture in traceroute, it can escape local network. DNS may not work (when i ping google.com it says "ping: unknown host google.com" after about 20 seconds) but i'm not sure if i even need if it's just for virtual system used as a database server.

Comment: I tried with DHCP but it doesn't seem to change anything.